# Phone Verification Error

Tags: android, verify

Hi I am trying to verify a phone number by sending a verification code using firebase, however, each time I try running the app it crashes saying "my app has stopped working" **in the `Logcat` I got these errors**

> 05-01 12:07:45.265 32229-32229/com.example.yaramedhat.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot create PhoneAuthCredential without either verificationProof, sessionInfo, ortemprary proof.
>           at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzbq.checkArgument(Unknown Source)
>           at com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthCredential.(Unknown Source)
>           at com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(Unknown Source)
>           at com.example.yaramedhat.myapplication.Loggedi$1.onClick(Loggedi.java:72)
>           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4475)
>           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18786)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
>           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

**and here is my code**

```
public class Loggedi extends AppCompatActivity {

    private PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks mCallbacks;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private String mVerificationId;
    private PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken mResendToken;


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_loggedi);


        final Button sendbtn;
        TextView textView;
        final EditText mobile, verification;




        sendbtn = findViewById(R.id.sendbtn);
        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        mobile = findViewById(R.id.mobile);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        verification = findViewById(R.id.verification);


        sendbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 mobile.setEnabled(false);
                sendbtn.setEnabled(false);

                String phone;
                phone = mobile.getText().toString();
                PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
                        phone,        // Phone number to verify
                        60,                 // Timeout duration
                        TimeUnit.SECONDS,   // Unit of timeout
                        Loggedi.this,
                        mCallbacks);

                String verificationcode  = verification.getText().toString();
                PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(mVerificationId, verificationcode);
                signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential);

            }
        });

        mCallbacks = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
            @Override
            public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
            signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(phoneAuthCredential);
            }

            @Override
            public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {
                Toast.makeText(Loggedi.this, "Invalid Verification", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
            @Override
            public void onCodeSent(String verificationId, PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken token) {

                mVerificationId = verificationId;
                mResendToken = token;
                sendbtn.setText("Verify Code");
            }
        };

        };

    private void signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task <AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Intent welcome = new Intent(Loggedi.this, welcomelayout.class);
                            startActivity(welcome);
                            finish();

                            FirebaseUser user = task.getResult().getUser();
                            // ...
                        } else {


                            if (task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                                Toast.makeText(Loggedi.this, "Invalid Verification Code", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you have any solution for this issue?